# Instagram is hacked

Tags: instagram

Someone has hacked my Instagram account neither my username exist now neither my phone number or my email is getting connected. I tried Facebook it says account does not exist what should I do?

Comment: Damn... Seems I was lucky, I only found 2000+ bogus follow actions, which basically means I will have to start over again I fear... .

Answer (score 1):

From [Instagram Help Center](https://help.instagram.com/149494825257596):

**If you're not able to log into your Instagram account**

If you can't access your account, you may be able to get additional help through the Instagram app:

1. Open the Instagram app on your mobile device
2. On the login screen, tap **Get help signing in** below **Log In**
3. For more options:

   - **On Android:**

     1. Tap Use **Username or Email**, then enter your username or email. Learn more about what you can do if you [don't know your username](https://help.instagram.com/1645522102409931?helpref=faq_content).
     2. Tap -> (right arrow) in the top right.
     3. Tap **Don't have access to any of these?** then follow the on-screen instructions. **Note:** If you think your username or email was changed as a result of your account being hacked, you can try these steps again using both your username and email.
   - **On iOS:**

     1. Enter your username or email. Learn more about what you can do if you [don't know your username](https://help.instagram.com/1645522102409931?helpref=faq_content).
     2. Tap **Other issues?** below **Send Login Link**, then follow the on-screen instructions. **Note:** If you think your username or email was changed as a result of your account being hacked, you can try these steps again using both your username and email.

Comment: Not useful in 2021

Comment: On Instagram official help page this information still exist. If it doesn't work for you, it doesn't mean it is not useful.

Comment: But the question is not about "what the official Instagram page says". The question is about how to solve the problem. And steps provided on the most official page don't make a sense if they are not reproducible. And I doubt that Instagram hardcoded another way of account access restoring procedure for me. Don't take it personally, I just look for a solution that work in real world, not on the any page on the world.

Comment: Let us know if you find that solution.